# No session persistance Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, persistence

I have a problem with Laravel authentication, I've already made a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470726/laravel-authentication-i-cant-retrieve-the-logged-in-user). After considering multiple things that could be wrong, I checked if there is something wrong with the sessions.

```
\Session::set('variableName', 1);
\Session::save();
var_dump(\Session::get('variableName'));
```

If I execute the above code in one HTTP request, get returns the value, but if I try \Session::get('variableName') in a different HTTP request it returns null.

My config/sessions.php:

```
return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => null,

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => null,

    'secure' => false,

];
```

There are session file being created in storage/framework/sessions.

Comment: When you say "different HTTP request," what do you mean exactly?  Is there any reason why a new session should be created?  For example, if you open a new Chrome tab in incognito mode, you'll get a new session.

Comment: No, a new session shouldn't be created. by different HTTP request I just mean going to a different URL and retrieving the session there.

Comment: Got it. What is your session driver?  According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#introduction if it is `array`: `sessions are stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests.`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session), you need to make sure you are not using `array` as your session driver since:

> Array sessions are stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests.